# Printing a file in it's binary form

Tags: c++, c, file-io

I want to make a c/c++ program to read a file and print it's binary form as the output.
I am able to print it in normal text form.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main()
{
FILE *fp;
char ch;

if((fp=fopen("C:\\Users\\!diot\\Desktop\\21.txt","rb"))==NULL)
{
    printf("\nCannot open file\n");
}

fseek(fp,0,SEEK_SET);

ch=getc(fp);

while(!feof(fp))
{
    putchar(ch);
    ch=getc(fp);
}


fclose(fp);

return(0);
}
```

But i want to print it's binary form.
So,please help.

Comment: Why do you need "binary" form?

Comment: Actually i want to work on a compression project.

Comment: Could you please clarify what exactly you need? Why don't you just use existing archive frameworks written in C++ then? You need some special algorithm?

Comment: It would be helpful if you can tell me more about them

Comment: KArchive can compress and decompress the common formats, like zip, rar, bzip2, etc... is that good for you?

Comment: "I want to make a c/c++ program". Pick a language, they're not the same!

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming by "binary" you mean, you want to see the contents as numerical data, instead of as ASCII text.  Change

```
  putchar(ch);
```

to

```
  printf("0x%02X ",ch);
  {
     static int counter=0;
     if ((++counter) % 16 == 0) printf("\n");
  }
```

This will display the file as hex data.

Of course, there are other ways of doing this. If you are using Visual Studio, just rename your file with a `.bin` extension, and then open it up directly with Visual Studio to view the hex data directly.  There are lots of freeware hex editors out there as well.

Comment: +1 for answering the question and attempting to intuit the OPs needs unclear though they are

Comment: I want to print it in binary form ,i.e., 0's and 1's only (machine language). Is there a method to do it or i will have to do it myself?

Comment: Some c libraries support the % b format for printf, but that is not standard.  You can loop over the 8 bits of each byte and printf "0" or "1"

Answer (score 0):

if you know what type of records have gone into the binary files. read it record by record. and then print each record. You got to use fread().

please refer tot his link. http://www.codingunit.com/c-tutorial-binary-file-io

Answer (score 0):

In C++, simply open your file in binary mode as:

```
fstream fs;
fs.open("filename.txt",ios::binary);
```

Comment: -1 because the method of reading the file is perfect acceptable c and works in c++ as well. The auther is opening the file in binary mode (see `"rb"` option to `fopen`)

Comment: @MarkLakata thanks!. I had no idea

Answer (score 0):

Inside you while loop, where you are reading each character (i.e. byte) at a time, you can do ANDing operation of character `ch` with all the characters from 00000001 to 10000000. Each time the output of the operation will let you know whether that particular bit is set or not. And you can use it for your further processing.